# Install Umbraco v5 via Webmatrix/WPI

Tags: windows-7, umbraco, webmatrix

I've 'successfully' installed Umbraco v5 via Webmatrix - running the site - ie hitting http://localhost/install returns the following error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:...\Umbraco CMS 5\bin\'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:...\Umbraco CMS 5\bin\'.

Any ideas? I've installed 4.x with no problems, but 5 is causing headaches...

EDIT: should add, I'm on Win7 at work, have installed successfully at home on Vista, using WebMatrix. Starting to get frustrating, since it's a top piece of gear and I'm keen to get moving with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every problem I have ever had w/regards to getting Umbraco running after install was always caused by permissions not being set correctly. Try granting 'EVERYONE' full read/write/modify access to the install directory and see if it helps.

Comment: This screams write permissions being the problem.

Comment: Got it sorted - realised I was trying to run from a network drive, moved it to the machine and all is well.